# メールとSMSの違いについて

Tags: mail

メールとSMSの違いについて調べているのですが、下記認識で合っていますか？

メール
・インターネット接続が必要
・メール サーバー を自前で構築可能
・電話回線は不要

SMS
・電話回線が必要(携帯電話回線はインターネットとは異なる？)
・インターネット接続は不要
・SMS サーバー を自前で構築不可

Answer (score 1, accepted):

あっているでしょう。他の違いを挙げるならメッセージ長 (SMS は文字通りショート) や課金体系 (SMS は通話料金) くらい？
 # LINE 等 SNS が普及してきた関係でどちらも廃れつつあったり・・・

メールサーバーを個人で構築して運用してよいかどうかの議論があったり
SMS を多要素認証に使ってよいとか良くないとかの議論があったり
話はいろいろ発展できますが、この質問の趣旨から外れますしこの辺で。